# On an AC-DC adapter, what is the use of the mA number printed on it?

Tags: charging, usb-device, ac-dc

releted to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1136028/how-to-reduce-usbs-1a-output-to-450ma) I wonder what the use of the number of `mA` printed on an AC-DC adapter/converter means.

I am charging a Bluetooth headset, which came with a AC-DC adapter, over USB using a "DIY-hybrid-cable" and it is working.
The original AC-DC plug (which I've cut) has `450mA` printed on it and the USB standard AC-DC plug, to which my "hybrid-cable" is connected, has `1.0A` printed on it.

> Does the `mA` number has any relevance? Why? I feel I am missing important knowledge.

Comment: A constant-voltage supply doesn't determine the current, the device does! A device that "wants" `450mA` of current will draw `450mA` whether the power supply can only provide `450mA`, or whether it could have supplied `500mA`, `1A`, or `2A`. The current rating of a supply is what it can deliver, not what it will force through the device.

Comment: You can test the item against those numbers; if it falls short in a test jig, it is likely to be malfunctioning.  There's a LOT more than two  numbers, though, to really characterize the power requirements; accuracy, overvoltage tolerance, ripple when lightly loaded... those aren't on the label.

Comment: A constant-voltage supply doesn't determine the current: the load, which in this case is the device, does. The current rating of a supply is what it can deliver, not what it will always force thru the load somehow. In that sense, unlike with voltage, the current rating of a power supply must be at least what the device wants but there is no harm in it being higher. A 9 volt 5 amp supply is a superset of a 9 volt 2 amp supply, for example.

Answer (score 1):

mA is milliamp is the current rating of the power supply, it depends on the device current consumption you are powering, when replacing adapter choose the same current rating (mA) or higher, but not lower